# Which set of functions/measures has range $\mathrm{L}^\infty$ under Fourier transformation

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, function-spaces

I have a question concerning the Fourier transformation. What I know is that $\mathrm{L}^{\infty}=\{\hat{u}:\ u\in Y\}$ for some space $Y$. Now, I want to specify the space $Y$. The question is, is there any explicit description of the space $Y$, i.e., of which form must $Y$ be such that the image under the Fourier transform of $\mathrm{L}^{\infty}$? I think $Y$ must contain Radon measures but otherwise I have no clue. Any suggestion? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: It is most unlikely that there is such an explicit  characterisation.  In fact, I would be so bold as to claim that if anybody were to find one, he would achieve instant fame ( well, at least amongst  the mathematical community).

Comment: You also need to specify which group you are implicitly considering in your question. $L^\infty$ of ***what?***

Comment: Moreover, there is a delicate question concerning what you are taking as the *domain* of your Fourier transform. A priori, the Fourier transform is defined for finite Radon measures on a LCA group; but then the range of the Fourier transform is almost never all of $L^\infty$ of the dual group. If you want to enlarge the domain of definition of the Fourier transform then you need to work out how you define the Fourier transform of something that isn't a measure ...

Comment: @YemonChoi : I am looking for $\mathrm{L}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$. However, it seems hopeless to get some nice answer to the question.